# How to manually start display resolution setting dialog?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I'm suffering from [a bug which requires me to set the display resolution after every boot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1615607) and a bug in the `unity` starter which prevents any results for search word `display` being displayed (it usually bring up the display settings dialog).

How can I start the display (arrangement/resolution) settings dialog from command line or otherwise without the unity launcher?

Comment: I'm also interested in fixing the laucher (including links in comments), but for this question I'd like to keep answers close to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is `unity-control-center display`

Check the man page for `unity-control-center`. There are options for other entries in the settings dialog. Once you know this, the sky is the limit - you can add that command as alias, function or part of script. You can also add it to be launched automatically once you log-in to Startup Applications or as `.desktop` file